# How to read a registry value into a label or msgbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I just need to read the DWord value in the registry of windows original install date into a label or textbox so that i can use it elsewhere. I am trying to create a countdown using the installdate.

I have Googled a lot, watched YouTube videos, copied and pasted a bunch of sample code to see if could make sense of what is required of me to achieve this and what would work

This is probably my 20th attempt

```
Dim InstallDate As Long

    With New RegRead
        .OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", KEY64)
        InstallDate =("InstallDate")
        .CloseKey()
    End With

    Label1.text=("Install date: " & Format$(DateAdd("s", InstallDate, #1/1/1970#), "Short Date"))
```

I expected the original install date to appear in lable1 in it decimal or hex value.

But it says 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level and Microsoft is a namespace and cannot be used as an expression. I am on Windows 7 64 bit, registry version 5. if that helps.

I am lost. Please help.(*i am just a rookie*)

Comment: Your line .OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", is missing the quotation marks in front of HKEY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds?view=netframework-4.8)

For example =>

```
Using rkLocalMachine As RegistryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
    Using sk As RegistryKey = rkLocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", False)
        Dim nValue As Integer = CType(sk.GetValue("InstallDate"), Integer)
        Dim dInstallDate As Date = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(nValue).DateTime
        MessageBox.Show("InstallDate = " + dInstallDate.ToString, "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim readValue = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(
    "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp", "Name", Nothing)
MsgBox("The value is " & readValue)
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/computer-resources/how-to-read-a-value-from-a-registry-key

Comment: Hi you guys, so taking everything i was given here and modifying and amending and   overwriting and all, i figured out this much so far. If I use it like this.Dim readValue As String
        readValue = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue _
        ("Hkey_Local_Machine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "ProductName", Nothing)
        TextBox1.Text = readValue. I can get the text value no problem. But not the numeric like for the installdate key. But thanks for the help so far. When i find the solution i will post it. Might help someone else. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you replied in an edit, I did a bit more research and found a article that address your issue.  In it the author states:  *I found that the registry already contains a value that indicates the number of seconds after January 1, 1970 @ 12:00 am that the operating system was installed.*  Here is his solution:

```
Public Shared Function GetWindowsInstallationDateTime(computerName as String) as DateTime
    Dim key as Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
    key = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, computerName)
    key = key.OpenSubKey("SOFTWAREMicrosoftWindows NTCurrentVersion", False)
    If key IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim startDate as DateTime
        Dim regVal as Int64

        startDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
        regVal = Convert.ToInt64(key.GetValue("InstallDate").ToString())

        Return startDate.AddSeconds(regVal)
    End If

    Return DateTime.MinValue
End Function
```

Source: https://alanjuden.com/2009/09/09/get-windows-installation-date-in-csharp-or-vb-net/

Hope this helps you solve your issue.